# How to document a Module that Exports an Instance of a Class with JSDoc

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

I'm working on a Javascript project where the default export (i.e. what you get when you require the module) is an instance of a class that extends a class.

For example:

```
/**
 * @module my-module-name
 */

/**
 * Private so documentation doesn't mention DefaultRouter
 * @private
 */
class DefaultRouter extends Router {
    /**
     * Extra method docs
     */
    extreMethod() {}
}
export default new DefaultRouter();
```

The documentation for this (ideally) would include the Router class (as that's available to developers) and show the API surface for the module as including docs for the extended class `Router` as well as the `extraMethod`.

I can get extraMethod docs showing up by using `@alias module:my-module-name.extraMethod` but I can't find a clean way to expose the `Router` methods.

How can I do this in a simpler way, e.g. with some `@` tag?

Answer (score 3):

After playing around a little, I found the `@borrows` tag that seems to work how I wanted it to.

```
/**
 * @module my-module-name
 * @borrows module:my-module-name.Router#methodName as methodName
 */
```